# How to include a formatted Epitech standard header in Vim by using gitbash in windows 10 system?

Tags: vim, header-files, git-bash

I'm setting up a work station at home by using a windows 10 system to do some homework from school. However, I am using Imac at school and it is easy to set up the standard header by using vim with the command + fn + F1. For my home station, I found the header file for my project and it instructed me to copy the file header.vim into ~/.vim/after/plugin/ folder then i will be set. But i still cant add the standard header in Vim text editor. So my question is how can i add the standard header in Vim and what command should i use to add the standard header by using gitbash on a pc(windows 10 system??

I've tried coppy the header.vim into ~/.vim/after/plugin/ folder and it seems not working

Comment: Welcome to [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) ! Not sure what you're trying to do here. Do you want to simply add a header comment in your file ? What does *the standard header* mean for you ? And what does `header.vim` contains ? For further questions around vim, there is a dedicated [Vi and Vim stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) :)

Comment: Note that vim on windows has a few oddities for paths (:help vimrc, :help runtimepath, maybe :help windows). Can you clarify “it’s not working” by [edit]ing your question?

Comment: I found several ways to handle the problem:
First: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/12/vi-and-vim-autocommand-3-steps-to-add-custom-header-to-your-file/
(which allowed me to create a link to custom my own created custom header by modify the file .vimrc).
Second is I have to create another directory with .vim/after/plugin then copy the file *.vim there. After that, everything is fix, just need to press F1 to add the custom header.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, I made a vim plugin to add a epitech header in your files that is very to install, you can check it here: https://github.com/x4m3/vim-epitech

Comment: I had 2min to browse the code and, well, putting filetype plugin on in an ftplugin just isnt going to work. It’s too late then.